# Swift compiler segfaulting in handleDeferredImports

Tags: ios, swift, clang

We have started seeing a strange problem, appearing somewhat out of nowhere, where the compiler segfaults in `handleDeferredImports`. This doesn't always happen, sometimes I need to clean & rebuild 2-3 times to trigger it again, so it's very hard to determine what's the root cause of it.

I've also not been able to reproduce it in a separate sample project, but after two days of looking for solutions I'm drawing a blank.

This is the segfault: `error: Segmentation fault: 11` with following stack:

```
0  swift                    0x000000011307064a PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 42
1  swift                    0x000000011306fdfe SignalHandler(int) + 302
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff76391b3d _sigtramp + 29
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 000000000000000000 _sigtramp + 2311513312
4  swift                    0x0000000110605df0 swift::ClangImporter::Implementation::handleDeferredImports() + 512
5  swift                    0x00000001106058dc swift::ClangImporter::Implementation::importHeader(swift::ModuleDecl*, llvm::StringRef, swift::SourceLoc, bool, std::__1::unique_ptr<llvm::MemoryBuffer, std::__1::default_delete<llvm::MemoryBuffer> >, bool) + 1804
6  swift                    0x0000000110606754 swift::ClangImporter::importBridgingHeader(llvm::StringRef, swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SourceLoc, bool, bool) + 932
7  swift                    0x000000011010acfd swift::CompilerInstance::performSema() + 2029
8  swift                    0x000000010f2f859b performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*, swift::UnifiedStatsReporter*) + 731
9  swift                    0x000000010f2f4dc5 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 7717
10 swift                    0x000000010f29aa35 main + 1349
11 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff761a808d start + 1
12 libdyld.dylib            0x0000000000000123 start + 2313519255
```

There's no indication to individual files or headers.

We do use a mix of Objective-C and Swift, importing `ProjectModuleName-Swift.h` in a lot of files, and similar, have a very large `ProjectModuleName-Bridging-Header.h` file. In addition to this, for legacy reasons, there's a `ProjectModuleName-Prefix.pch` for default Objective-C includes (yes, I know that's awful).

What's strange here is the segfault in `handleDeferredImports` which is different from all the other Swift compiler segfault issues found on Stack Overflow.

Swift version is 4.2, and we're using the "New Build System" in Xcode 10 (it also segfaults on the "Legacy Build System").

Comment: Have you tried this? Step 1) You can remove half of the files from the project, make sure the rest compiles (it doesn't have to be a running program), and see if the problem still exists. If you fixed it, remove the other half instead. Step 2) Do step 1 as often as possible. - You will need some version control for this (a local git repo is enough), because there will be some trial and error..

Comment: A crash by the compiler is always a bug in the compiler, so you'll definitely want to open a defect at bugs.swift.org. It's definitely related to the bridging header, so removing that would be a big start (I mean removing in the same way @Michael does; temporarily, commenting out anything that relies on it just to see if you can at what point you can get things to compile).

Comment: Do make sure to delete DerivedData. This does feel like the kind of crash that will fix.

Comment: @Michael for a product level project? We're talking thousands of files. And with the issue not happening consistently, I can remove files, it might build, and then maybe it'll break again half an hour later.

Comment: @RobNapier I opened up https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-9528 , but without being able to isolate the error in a reproducible project, it's going to be very hard to fix the problem.

Also, Xcode clean should delete DerivedData, no?

Comment: No; Xcode clean is not the same as deleting DerivedData. "Clean Build Folder" (Cmd-Shift-Opt K) is close, but even that isn't quite a powerful as deleting DerivedData.

Comment: Regarding Michael's approach, while difficult, it's exactly how I've done this with massive projects in the past. The fact that it doesn't fail reliably suggests that you may need to script it out with `xcodebuild` to try building repeatedly to see if you can find a reliable number of builds that will cause the problem. In any case, you're going to have to hunt for a "it works in this case, but not in this case" situation in order to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround for the Swift 4 compiler was to enable `Whole Module` optimisation for all builds.

The issue itself appears to been fixed in Swift 5.0

Should anyone see this issue in the future, please refer to https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-9528